# How to use Predict in rms package for a multiple values?

Tags: r, machine-learning, predict, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I used cox model for `Predict` function rms package for individual values they are returning the correct result where as when I give multiple values it gives me weired results?

```
library(data.table)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(rms)
```

`dput(df)`

```
structure(list(ID = c(1001L, 1002L, 1003L, 1004L, 1006L, 1014L, 
1015L, 1016L, 1018L, 1022L, 1024L, 1032L, 1040L, 1042L, 1049L, 
1056L, 1059L, 1060L, 1066L, 1084L, 1087L, 1090L, 1093L, 1096L, 
1097L, 1098L, 1099L, 1200L, 1205L, 1216L, 1221L, 1222L, 1225L, 
1226L, 1233L, 1239L), Time = c(9L, 8L, 69L, 104L, 104L, 100L, 
24L, 85L, 100L, 99L, 67L, 58L, 7L, 94L, 93L, 90L, 91L, 90L, 89L, 
72L, 84L, 84L, 11L, 82L, 39L, 46L, 82L, 82L, 9L, 34L, 75L, 76L, 
52L, 20L, 29L, 70L), Event = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Risk1 = c(0.1, 
0.03, 0.02, 0.05, 0.01, 0.04, 0.03, 0.06, 0.02, 0.03, 0, 0, 0.11, 
0.01, 0.03, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.04, 0, 0.07, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0), Risk2 = c(88L, 49L, 60L, 
46L, 50L, 60L, 38L, 74L, 39L, 65L, 80L, 35L, 54L, 40L, 54L, 55L, 
60L, 38L, 64L, 74L, 71L, 57L, 55L, 49L, 42L, 30L, 63L, 46L, 47L, 
58L, 34L, 72L, 50L, 60L, 73L, 51L), Risk3 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L)
```

followed by

```
ddist <- datadist(df)
options(datadist='ddist')

cox_model <-cph(Surv(Time,Event==1) ~ Risk1 + Risk2 + Risk3, x = T, y = T, data = df, surv = T)
Predict(cox_model, Risk1=3.2, Risk2=1, Risk3=0.5)
```

[image: output1]

but when I give multiple values as follows:

```
Predict(cox_model,
    Risk1=c(5,3,2,1.5,1.5,2,3,2.5,4,2,5.5,6,3,3.5,4,5,4.5,3,2,6,3,5,4,1.8,3,3.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,5,6,4,1.5,5,4,2.5),
    Risk2=c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0),
    Risk3=c(0,0.07,0,0.03,0.01,0.02,0.01,0,0.05,0,0.04,0.03,0.01,0.01,0.01,0,0.11,0.03,0,0.05,0,0,0.02,0.04,0.01,0,0,0.01,0.03,0,0.01,0,0.06,0,0,0.1))
```

It gives me a ouput with `46566` rows where as I have only `36` rows to predict

[image: output2]

Comment: Not sure it helps but in case you didn't notice, 46566 = 36*36*36 (so it makes all possible combinations with the values you provided)

Comment: ya that's right. Is there any way to remove the combinations and keep only required items in the dataframe?